# Replace a string in file with new string containing $ sign in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to replace string with a new string containing `$`(dollar) sign in a existing file.

I have used below (regex) line in my code but I am not able get the expected result. Please suggest the solution.

```
system("perl -pi -e \"s/length\\s+.*/length [index $pkt_len]/g if /^\\s*set_value\\s+length/\" $filename")
```

Comment: Could you please mention the input string?

Comment: set_value length 1 . Instead of $ symbol its value is printed

Comment: Instead of calling a new `perl` process from within a `perl` process, you could also do everything in the first `perl`. Please show the content of the file `$filename`, the value of `$pkt_len` and what should be the expected output (the new content of `$filename`)

Comment: Not that you should do this, but it you want to call `perl` from within a Perl program, you should use `$^X`. That's the current perl binary that's running. If plain `perl` finds another one in your path but uses your current environment, you can get mismatches in library versions.

Comment: in the $filename i want to replace "set_value length 1" string with "set_value length [index $pkt_len]". i am able to replace but instead of $ symbol it's value is appearing in the file.

Answer (score 1):

The way to find the solution is during debug you should print out the line of the system call and test it "by hand" if it works as expected in the shell.

My guess is that

```
system("perl -pi -e 's/length\\s+.*/length [index \\\$pkt_len]/g if /^\\s*set_value\\s+length/' $filename")
```

is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need 7 backslashes (!):

```
system("echo a | perl -pe \"s/a/\\\\\\\$foo/\"");
```

**Output**:

```
$foo
```

- First `"echo a | perl -pe \"s/a/\\\\\\\$foo/\""` is interpreted by `perl` which reduces the string to `echo a | perl -pe "s/a/\\\$foo/"`
- Then it is parsed by the shell `sh` to give : `echo a | perl -pe s/a/\$foo/`
- Finally, it is parsed by `perl` a second time to give the output `$foo`.